# Why is Login Event listener called multiple times?

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security

I have registered a login even listener.

My listener is defined as

```
class LoginEventListener implements
    ApplicationListener<InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent> {

    //deal with successful login
    void onApplicationEvent(InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent event) {
        User.withNewTransaction {

            def user = User.findById(event.authentication.principal.id)
            if(!user.isAttached())
                user.attach()


            log.error "logged in as .... " + user.email


        }


    }


}
```

My resources is defined as  conf/spring/resources.groovy

```
beans = {

    loginEventListener(LoginEventListener)
}
```

In the logs i see that login event listener fires up multiple times in a row. I am wondering why is this happening?

```
ERROR 2017-06-05 12:27:16,005 [ajp-bio-8109-exec-2903] LoginEventListener: logged in as .... bdayley@asd.com
ERROR 2017-06-05 12:27:16,290 [ajp-bio-8109-exec-2903] LoginEventListener: logged in as .... bdayley@asd.com
ERROR 2017-06-05 12:27:16,364 [ajp-bio-8109-exec-2903] LoginEventListener: logged in as .... bdayley@asd.com
ERROR 2017-06-05 12:27:16,419 [ajp-bio-8109-exec-2890] LoginEventListener: logged in as .... bdayley@asd.com
ERROR 2017-06-05 12:27:16,421 [ajp-bio-8109-exec-2901] LoginEventListener: logged in as .... bdayley@asd.com
ERROR 2017-06-05 12:27:16,424 [ajp-bio-8109-exec-2898] LoginEventListener: logged in as .... bdayley@asd.com
ERROR 2017-06-05 12:27:16,426 [ajp-bio-8109-exec-2891] LoginEventListener: logged in as .... bdayley@asd.com
ERROR 2017-06-05 12:27:16,433 [ajp-bio-8109-exec-2878] LoginEventListener: logged in as .... bdayley@asd.com
```

Comment: please provide how you create events

Comment: Is it always the same amount of times? Are you certain the code is actually being fired that many times? Have you put a breakpoint in the method to be sure of it?

Comment: the error only happens sometimes. Out of 10 users for 2 users the event listener is being fired multiple times. Inside the login listener i have just put log.error "......" to verify whether the listener is being fired multiple times in a row.